# Gradle could not resolve org.springframework.vault:spring-vault-core

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, spring-cloud-vault-config

I have a project that adopts **Spring Vault** to fetch credential. Dependencies of the project are as following and `build.gradle` file is generated automatically afterwards.

[image]

When I build the project I got the error

> Could not resolve
> org.springframework.vault:spring-vault-core:2.2.2.RELEASE.
>
> Possible solution:
>
> - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html

I have checked the libraries by going to the **Project Structures** and got the weird thing

[image]

The weird thing I mean here is about the path of the jar file. It should be something like

`%GRADLE_HOME%\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.cloud\spring-cloud-vault-config\2.2.3.RELEASE\5fd5a06deb01db77eb3e9b8e723ccc1e0790c420`

How can I fix this issue in IntelliJ?

Comment: There is an issue atht when the library cannot be resolved its path will contain such error:  https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-176838 But this should not be the reason of the problem. Can you build this project from command line by Gradle?

Comment: I got the following log by cmd

     Required by:
         project : > org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-vault-config:2.2.4.RELEASE
         project : > org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-vault-config:2.2.4.RELEASE > org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-vault-config:2.2.4.RELEASE
      > Could not resolve org.springframework.vault:spring-vault-core:2.2.0.RELEASE.
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/vault/spring-vault-core/2.2.0.RELEASE/spring-vault-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.pom'.

Comment: This means you need to fix it in Maven. Check your network settings. If you have a proxy, configure it in Maven settings. Verify that https certificate is correct and is not replaced by the proxy (if you have it in network).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you get an error about could not resolve dependencies in `gradle`, then there are several things you need to check.

1. Proxy settings (should be inside `gradle.properties`)
2. Permission for creating directories (particularly in `%GRADLE_HOME%\caches\modules-2\files-2.1`)

For the problem of proxy setting, simply set values for the following fields inside gradle.properties

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=
systemProp.http.proxyPort=
systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=
systemProp.https.proxyHost=
systemProp.https.proxyPort=
systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=
```

For the problem of permission, try creating directories with the name of dependencies cannot be resolved, for example, `org.springframework.vault` at `%GRADLE_HOME%\caches\modules-2\files-2.1`. If you got permission denied or simply cannot create, then please contact your IT support!

Comment: I also had the proxy issue and I missed while trying to upgrade the log4j jar. Saw your answer and fixed the issue instantly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the version of Spring Cloud in your build.gradle

Here's an example using the Kotlin-Gradle pluggin:

```
(1) extra["springCloudVersion"] = "2022.0.4"

(2) dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${property("springCloudVersion")}")
    }
}
```